# Relationship between Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC) and the Pearson's Chi-square

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, references

I would like to find a reference showing that the MCC follows a Chi-square distribution. This is suggested in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient, as they claim that MCC = sqrt(Chi-square/n).

Does it mean the MCC follows the Chi-square distribution? And where can I find the proof of this equation? I tried with the equations of MCC and Chi-square but could not make them equal.

Many thanks for any help/guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be just the [$\phi$ coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Measures_of_association) ... i.e. much older than Matthews' paper. (edit: I missed it the first time through but they do actually mention it in the MCC article you link).

Clearly if its square was actually distributed as a $\chi^2/N$, $\phi$ *could not* itself be chi-squared. However, the chi-squared statistic is not actually distributed as chi-squared either; it's discrete. Rather, it is the case that $N\phi^2$ is asymptotically $\chi^2_1$.

Under the null of no association, $\phi$ will asymptotically have a (scaled) $\chi_1$ distribution with a random sign attached ... which would be Gaussian.

As for showing the connection between the $\phi$ coefficient and the chi-squared statistic in a $2\times 2$ table, 
if we label the 4 entries $\begin{matrix}_A & _B\\ ^C & ^D\end{matrix}$ notice that each $O_{ij} - E_{ij}= \pm(AD-BC)/N$, where $N$ is the sum of the entries.